# How to force increase the size of a range-bytes response for videos in Apache?

Tags: apache, http, browser, safari, video-streaming

The newest version of Safari (mobile & desktop) buffers videos 4x slower than other browsers because it sends many small sized range-bytes requests opposed to a few large ones. An example request and response is below (this request continues with a small size of 64kb until enough data is loaded for the video to play, in Chrome, Firefox and other browsers the range-bytes request is much larger and so the data is delivered much faster in one stream).

Is it possible to get around this issue by forcing my web server (apache) to ignore Safari's small range-byte request of 64kb, and instead send a larger amount of data (about 5MB)? The request is made directly to the video file.

```
Summary
URL: http://example.org/video.mp4?rand=942824
Status: 206 Partial Content
Source: Network

Request
GET /video.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Range: bytes=0-65535
Accept-Encoding: identity

Response
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 0-65535/467342440
Accept-Ranges: 0-467342440
Content-Length: 65536
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.2.1
```

UPDATE: I managed to change the request range header using the below code, however even though the 5mb is downloaded quickly, safari continues sending these small 64kb range requests and ignores the 5mb that was downloaded so this is not a solution.

```
SetEnvIf Range bytes=0-65535 HAVE_MyRequestHeader
RequestHeader unset Range env=HAVE_MyRequestHeader
RequestHeader set Range bytes=0-5000000 env=HAVE_MyRequestHeader
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can not change it server side. The client makes a request the server fulfills the request. Sending data the client didn’t ask for will likely cause errors.